# Update the variant product title and excerpt permanently

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, import, export

I have tried to update the variant product title and excerpt by import CSV. It is updated in the database.

After doing this I tried to update product info from the admin panel and open variation from the admin panel its reverts with the old title as it is.
Is there any process to update variants title and excerpt and it will not revert back?

Is it possible or not?

I want to update permanently title and excerpt of `post_type=product_variation`

Please check the screenshot:
https://prnt.sc/xd6qez

https://prnt.sc/xfml9z

Thanks